# Surround a substring of string with a span tag while avoiding html already there

Tags: javascript

My question is confusing, so I will clarify.  I have two strings.  Here they are...

```
let htmlStr = "  paramount    13.11 nowe    soxxxxxx 23  diablo  13<span class='mark' style='background: lime'>.</span>11     .twisted sister   13.11 special 13.45 way"
let rawStr = "  paramount    13.11 nowe    soxxxxxx 23  diablo  13.11     .twisted sister   13.11 special 13.45 way"
```

I have a rawStr which contains no html and I have an htmlStr with contains the same thing as rawStr, but with html.  I have a starting index and an ending index.  Suppose my starting index is 50 and my ending index is 55.  So what do I need to find?  Well I would simply do this

```
rawStr.substring(startingIndex, endingIndex) //13.11
```

Okay. so I know I'm looking for the second occurrence of this substring "13.11" in the htmlStr.  Okay using my human eye, I see it, it looks this

[image]

You can see the 13.11, just with html in there.  Well I want to skip over the span tag with the class "mark" and apply span tags with class "dsa" and red background to "13" and "11" so the resulting htmlStr should look like this

```
 let htmlStr = "  paramount    13.11 nowe    soxxxxxx 23  diablo  <span class='dsa' style='background-color:red'>13</span><span class='mark' style='background: lime'>.</span><span class='class='dsa' background-color: red'>11</span>     .twisted sister   13.11 special 13.45 way";
```

Of course if there were no "mark" span tags present to begin with, then the whole substring would be surrounded with a span with a class "dsa" with red background.

How can I achieve this?

Some additional clarification.  The start and end indexes corresponds to the rawStr.  It just so happens that in this one particular case that is "13.11".  It could have been anything.  It could be numbers, special chars, letters, anything standard. When I do rawStr.substring(startingIndex, endingIndex)  I know I get "13.11" in this example.  With my human eye, I can see that this is the second occurrence of this substring, The first one has no html, and third one has no html.  I don't care about those, since my index told me to care only about the second occurrence which has the unfortunate luck of having html in-between it.  Okay, so I want to put a span tag around "13.11", but I can't because the "." so happens to have the mark span to it, so instead I want to put a span tag around "13" and another around "11" essentially skipping whatever mark is "which happens to be the '.'".

If you prefer, here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ewdochf4/)

Comment: can you share what you are trying to acheive as well? not ```htmlStr``` out put but how you want to use it, you might get better answer.

Comment: I thought I did that. I have some text that need to be marked in a document. The document is a huge string array of lines. In the backend, I get back a message that tells me which text need to be marked. The response only gives me starting and ending index.  The app was orginally written in C++, which surprisingly is simpler to do in, but since this needs to be in a browser, I have to consider html, something I don't have to in C++

Comment: I'm not sure to perfectly understand the whole scenario. If you had a string html encoded and you needed to know its text content as rendered it was as easy as using [DOMParser: parseFromString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString) and retrieve `.documentElement.textContent` from the returned object. But I'm afraid it's not what you actually need.

Comment: ok now I get it... do you always only need to find numbers like those in the string? and is only the dot represented (optionally) as a `span.mark`?

Comment: @DiegoD Afraid not.  Indeed, if I only wanted to know the text content, I would do just that .textContent and get "13.11".  I already know it's "13.11", I need to apply styles to "13" and "11" and skip the "." because it already has the "mark" span tag to it.

If I was given a different startingIndex and endingIndex whereupon there is no "mark" span tag at all for the substring within those indexes, I simply just need to surround "13.11" with a span with class "dsa" and red background color.  That I can do, that part is simple, it's when there is html inbetween what I want

Comment: @DiegoD Well in this particular example the substring, just happens to be "13.11" and the mark tag just so happens to be applied to the ".".  That isn't always the case, in fact it rarely is.  The mark tag could be anything, not necessarily a "."  It could of been the case that the mark tag was applied to 3.1 or just 11

Comment: @DiegoD, yeah, it's not always numbers, it can literally be any character.  Notice the word "paramount"  it could of been that.  There could have existed something like this
"    param<span class='mark' style='background-color: red'>ount

Comment: I was attempting at a solution engaging regular expressions... and the world knows how inconsistent can be using regex for parsing html. The point here is taking things for granted so that such solution would be granted to work given those conditions. But if so far I understand that you have two numbers that might be separated by an html tag (being a `span` and having the class `mark`) now you are saying that such tag  could also wrap the numbers or portions of the numbers.. and the separator could be anything. The regex is no more safe here and I'm afraid there's too much ambiguity to parse

Comment: before in the question you talked about two indexes...now you made an example of `para` and `mount` but it's not clear if the word you are looking for is `paramount` in any possible shape like `para<whatever>mount` `p<whatever>aramount` and so on.. or if you give 2 exact halves and you must find them separated like that or at best already joint together

Comment: @DiegoD think of it this way. I'm given two indexes. A start and an end. With that start and end, using the raw string, I know the substring I'm looking for just so happens to be "13.11" (it literally could be anything though, numbers, letters, anything).  So, armed with this knowledge of "13.11" I know given the indexes this is the second occurence of that term, but there is HTML inbetween it. The HMTL will always be span with class "mark" if it exist. I want to put span tag around "13" skip over whatever mark is (could be anything) and put a span tag around "11" with class "dsa"

Comment: What if there was already a `span` wrapping the text "diablo  13". Then what should happen?

Comment: @trincot nothing, since it isn't the substring found using rawStr(startIndex, endIndex).  I only care about what that substring tells me, which in this case is "13.11"

Comment: I mean, in your example string, there *is* 13.11 after "diablo ". So what if the first string has halfway `<span>diablo 13</span><span>.</span>11` (so with the extra span), and the raw string is like you provided it, then what happens? Will that first (extra) span be cut? Will nothing change? Will only 11 be wrapped into a new span?

Comment: @trincot right, yeah that scenario would never happen.  It could, if I allow another function in my app to be used while I'm doing this thing I wanting to do in my question, but that is turned off, so there will not be any other spans.  The only other span that could happen is at the very beginning of the string there could be <span class='highlight'>...</span>, but that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: So there will be one span inside? Then what if we have `<span>diablo 13</span>.11` in the middle, and the raw string is like you have it. Then what happens? Also, if there is indeed `<span class='highlight'>...</span>` in the beginning, then will the raw string also start with `...`?

Comment: @trincot The span tag that already exist in the htmlStr will be the mark span tag.  It's possible the mark span tag is "diablo 13", so essentially  ... <span class='mark'>diablo 13></span>... would already be there, in which case I would skip over it since it has the "mark" class.  However the indexes in that case would never be the indexes that "diablo 13" is. The start and end indexes I get are always before or after mark (if mark span exist), never in it.

Comment: It is not clear to me what the constraints are. I will leave this for someone else.

Comment: @trincot i'm probably going to have to delete this post and I guess better articulate what I'm trying to achieve. To me its simple, but I can see how it can be somewhat confusing.